# How to install color palettes from *.sh files in tilda?

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors, tilda

I don't like any of the built in color palettes in tilda.  How do I install another from a `.sh` file?

For instance: https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell/blob/master/base16-google.dark.sh

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/blob/master/autogen.sh
I had the same problem, that's why started to use Weebly and Mobirise

Comment: Please include essential parts here.